# Looping through get_dns_record

Tags: php, arrays

Heres a quick rundown of whats going on and where the problem is...
$_POST['domain_list'] is an array of domains the user can enter seperated by line breaks (hence the explode on \n)
The first var dump gives me:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(11) "google.com " [1]=> string(17) "websolutions.com " [2]=> string(12) "facebook.com" }
```

Which is what I want - The 3 hostnames I entered in the textarea.

So then the first foreach is looping through that array and assigning each hostname to the dns_get_record function.

Which leads to the problem I'm having - The 2 loops inside that pull the IP and Nameservers, only pull the last domain. So those 2 var dumps look something like:

```
array(5) { ["host"]=> string(12) "facebook.com" ["type"]=> string(1) "A" ["ip"]=> string(13) "173.252.120.6" ["class"]=> string(2) "IN" ["ttl"]=> int(900) } Hostname: facebook.com IP: 173.252.120.6
array(5) { ["host"]=> string(12) "facebook.com" ["type"]=> string(2) "NS" ["target"]=> string(17) "a.ns.facebook.com" ["class"]=> string(2) "IN" ["ttl"]=> int(172528) } Hostname: facebook.com NS: a.ns.facebook.com
array(5) { ["host"]=> string(12) "facebook.com" ["type"]=> string(2) "NS" ["target"]=> string(17) "b.ns.facebook.com" ["class"]=> string(2) "IN" ["ttl"]=> int(172528) } Hostname: facebook.com NS: b.ns.facebook.com
```

For some reason, the main loop isn't working like I expect it to, I was expecting it to loop through the entire $domain array (which you can see in the first var_dump, it DOES have all 3 domains in the array)

```
if ( isset( $_POST['domain_list'] ) ) {

    $domain = $_POST['domain_list'];
    $domain = explode( "\n", $domain );
    var_dump( $domain );

    foreach ( $domain as $entry ) {
        $a_record = dns_get_record( $entry, DNS_A );
        $nameservers = dns_get_record( $entry, DNS_NS );

        foreach($a_record as $arr1) {
            var_dump($arr1);
            echo 'Hostname: '.$arr1['host'].' IP: '.$arr1['ip'] . '<br>';
        }

        foreach($nameservers as $arr2) {
            var_dump($arr2);
            echo 'Hostname: '.$arr2['host'].' NS: '.$arr2['target'] . '<br>';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "failed";
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code works fine. Output: https://gist.github.com/ceejayoz/418046981f5cf311881a

Comment: Worked for me, I have records for all the domains.

Comment: That is interesting. I cannot get that result after testing in a few different environments. Perhaps it could be server-related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the comments were correct - My code was actually working properly. The reason I was not getting the same results was the way I was exploding on the line breaks from the textarea.

In order to correctly get the values seperated by line breaks in the textarea, I updated this line:

```
$domain = explode( "\n", $domain );
```

to

```
$domain = explode( "\r\n", $domain );
```

Amazing how something so simple can drive one so crazy!